# Using select2's selected option value in a rails forms field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

How do I assign the selected option value:

```
<select class="select2-simple-dropdown">
    <% Season.all.each do |season| %>
        <option id="chosen-season" value="<%= season.id %>"><%= season.name %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

To a form's field, let's say: `Voyage.given_season` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rails select field instead and do it like this

```
<%= f.select :season_id, Season.all.pluck(:name, :id), {},
                         { class: 'select2-simple-dropdown'}  %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't need the `.all`

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery is also right, it works without `.all`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your select input to accept multiple options, you can pass multiple: true

```
<%= f.select(:season_id,  Season.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id] }, class: "form-control select2-simple-dropdown", id: "list-markets", multiple: true) %>
```

https://aalvarez.me/posts/select2-with-simple-form-in-rails/